# Close Other tabs in XCode 4?

Tags: xcode4

Am I crazy or is it not possible to close other tabs in XCode 4? I have about 7 tabs opened littering my workspace. I right click the one tab I'm interested in to bring up the context menu. I can see options to open a "new tab", "close tab", "close other tabs", and "move tab to new window". However, the only option that is not greyed out is "new tab". Do I have to put XCode in some magical state to enable the other options? Are these options merely eye candy, teasing me with hopes and aspirations of things I might like to do? Is this some weird kind of year long April fools gag? Inquiring minds wanna know.
***Update Uploading a HocusFocus screen capture for clarity...**
[image]

Comment: I've updated my question to point out the menu item I'm asking about since there appears to be confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to hover over the tab and click on the cross that appears on the left hand side of the tab. However, if you are not seeing this cross for some strange reason - you should be able to close the current tab in XCode (similar to many other OSX applications) by pressing CMD+W on your keyboard.

While the context menu doesn't work when you right click on a tab, you can achieve all of the same results by using keyboard shortcuts (which do seem to work as expected). Each of the 4 options on the context menu maps to the following shortcuts;

New Tab: CMD + T

Close Tab: CMD + W

Close Other Tabs: CMD + ALT + W

Move Tab to Other Window: I couldn't find a keyboard shortcut, but you can click and drag the tab away from the menu bar.

There doesn't appear to be a sensible way to enable the context menu on the tabs at the current time.

Comment: I don't want to close the current tab. I want to close all other tabs. There is a disavled option in the right mouse context menu that I can't seem to enable. It looks like a nasty prank.

Comment: Not sure how or why but Cmd+Alt+W does the trick! Still not sure why the options are grayed out in the right mouse ctx menu. May I ask how you found this shortcut?

Comment: If you go to 'XCode -> Preferences' (Cmd+,) and then go to the Key Bindings tab, you'll see a massive list of all of the keyboard shortcuts that XCode has to offer. Luckily, you can filter through them (if you type in 'tabs', you'll see the 'Close Other Tab' short-cut). There are even some commands that aren't even bound to keys yet!

No idea why it's apparently impossible to get the items to show on the context menu. I'm sure that will come in a future XCode update.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I still don't know why the right mouse context menu option is always grayed out! That makes absolutely no sense and is completely frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but are/were you in full screen? Try again after quitting full screen...

Comment: Did it for me it did. It just does not work in fullscreen, and we're in 2015 with Xcode 7. Time to jetpack home.

Answer (score 1):

Just click: View -> Hide tab bar

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (I say 'similar, because using Cmd+W. Cmd+Alt+W' didn't work for me).

In my case the tab had a cross on the top right, grayed out and nothing happens when clicking on it. If I opened a new tab, I could close either of the extra tabbed editors, but not both(!)

In View > Editor, selecting 'Standard' removes the 'second tabbed editor'.

Comment: I am not understanding why XCode 4 just feels generally broken! I just upgraded to XCode 4.0.2 and it still doesn't let me close other tabs via the context menu. Cmd+Alt+W works and was really what I was looking for in the 1st place. (A hot key vs. a menu opt.)